# Language-agnostic Rules Specification

Tags: configuration, cross-platform, rules

One of the requirements in my current project is to be able to select a target URL for a client based on certain conditions, and these conditions may have AND/OR operators and have nested conditions as well. A rudimentary cooked-up example:

```
if (device == 'android' || device == 'iOS') {
    if ( (flag1 == 'x' && productId == 'ABC123') || (flag1 == 'y' && productId == 'EFG345') ) {
      return url1;
    }
}
else if (device == 'mac' || device == 'windows') {
   ...
}
```

Pretty simple if you are building this service, but our challenge is that this logic needs to be supplied to our vendors, who take care of the URL selection for specific sections of our customer base, and they all use different implementation languages - Java, Go-Lang, Python, you name it.

The question is, assuming the variables such as device, flag1, productId, etc. are already populated, is there a language agnostic way of specifying these rules, like in a JSON for example?

I looked at: [Representing logic as data in JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20737045/representing-logic-as-data-in-json)

and I like the suggestion to use something like:

```
["AND",
    {"var1" : "value1"},
    ["OR",
        { "var2" : "value2" },
        { "var3" : "value3" }
    ]
]
```

But I don't see any standard parsers that can read this JSON and apply the rules in a specific language of choice. Are there any standard solutions out there to help with this requirement, without having multiple custom parsers and implementations that are prone to error?

P.S: We can have each of our vendor write their own snippet for this selection logic, but the challenge is the rules may change quite frequently, and we don't want to wait for several different companies to roll out code changes to their systems every time we change a rule. We also thought of writing a service and having the vendors call us, so that there is centralized access to these rules, but this means an extra network call (or have the maintain a cache and keep polling our service). Further, not all vendors are open to the idea of calling a service at the time of URL selection.

Comment: Right, there's no standard parser other than the one that's part of your language of choice. But parsing JSON is simple in most languages, as is evaluating a tree of conditions. If you want a standard parser, you have to create it.

Comment: Thanks CHao. The challenge is if we build a custom parser for the condition tree evaluation, every one of our vendor needs to do it, and it can quickly turn into a maintenance nightmare :)

Comment: Your vendors might not be all that open to contacting a service, but they're probably even less open to implementing their own parser for a data format they have no control over. If you insist on handing them data in a nonstandard format (and let's be clear here: *any* logic-as-data format is going to be nonstandard), you'd better be willing to write the parser library for them. Otherwise, provide a single URL that accepts any request and forwards it to the right URL.

Answer (score 2):

I've created a JSON schema to describe your logic types:

```json
{
  "id": "http://json-schema.org/geo",
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-06/schema#",
  "description": "A languge-independent logic representation",
  "$ref": "#/definitions/Term",
  "definitions": {
    "Term": {
      "type": "object",
      "additionalProperties": false,
      "description": "A logical value",
      "properties": {
        "kind": { "$ref": "#/definitions/Kind" },
        "x": { "$ref": "#/definitions/Term" },
        "y": { "$ref": "#/definitions/Term" },
        "value": { "$ref": "#/definitions/Value" }
      },
      "required": ["kind"],
      "title": "Term"
    },
    "Value": {
      "type": "object",
      "additionalProperties": false,
      "description": "A key-value term",
      "properties": {
        "key": { "type": "string" },
        "value": { "type": "string" }
      },
      "required": [ "key", "value"],
      "title": "Term"
    },
    "Kind": {
      "description": "The kind of term",
      "type": "string",
      "enum": ["and", "or", "not", "value"],
      "title": "Kind"
    }
  }
}
```

Here's an example of data that conforms to the schema (note that I've structured it slightly more regularly than your example):

```json
{
  "kind": "and",
  "x": {
    "kind": "value",
    "value": { "key": "var1", "value": "value1" }
  },
  "y": {
    "kind": "or",
    "x": {
      "kind": "value",
      "value": { "key": "var2", "value": "value2" }
    },
    "y": {
      "kind": "value",
      "value": { "key": "var3", "value": "value3" }
    }
  }
}
```

(I think you could play with the schema to get something more succinct and/or more typesafe).

I've used [quicktype](https://app.quicktype.io/?gist=2c9dce4022d3e4987a6e8b48752850cc) to generate types and JSON marshaling code in C++, Go, Swift, Objective-C, Java, C#, JavaScript, and more. For example, here is the [Swift](https://app.quicktype.io/?gist=2c9dce4022d3e4987a6e8b48752850cc&l=swift) representation and parsing instructions:

```swift
// To parse the JSON, add this file to your project and do:
//
//   let term = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Term.self, from: jsonData)

import Foundation

/// A logical value
class Term: Codable {
    let kind: Kind
    let x, y: Term?
    let value: TermValue?
}

/// The kind of term
enum Kind: String, Codable {
    case and = "and"
    case not = "not"
    case or = "or"
    case value = "value"
}

/// A key-value term
struct TermValue: Codable {
    let key, value: String
}
```

And here's the Go implementation:

```go
// To parse and unparse this JSON data, add this code to your project and do:
//
//    term, err := UnmarshalTerm(bytes)
//    bytes, err = term.Marshal()

package main

import "encoding/json"

func UnmarshalTerm(data []byte) (Term, error) {
    var r Term
    err := json.Unmarshal(data, &r)
    return r, err
}

func (r *Term) Marshal() ([]byte, error) {
    return json.Marshal(r)
}

// A logical value
type Term struct {
    Kind  Kind       `json:"kind"` 
    X     *Term      `json:"x"`    
    Y     *Term      `json:"y"`    
    Value *TermValue `json:"value"`
}

// A key-value term
type TermValue struct {
    Key   string `json:"key"`  
    Value string `json:"value"`
}

// The kind of term
type Kind string
const (
    And Kind = "and"
    Not Kind = "not"
    Or Kind = "or"
    Value Kind = "value"
)
```

Go to https://app.quicktype.io/?gist=2c9dce4022d3e4987a6e8b48752850cc to play with the schema and generate code for various languages. You still need to define the evaluation function in each language, though.

Comment: I've already made a small improvement my using an array of `children: Term[]` rather than nullable `x` and `y` members. You should keep playing until you get a representation that works for you.